# ES6 Aurelia dependency injection confusion

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, ecmascript-6, aurelia

according to what I've read on the blogs, here is how you do DI in Aurelia and ES6, but it doesn't work.

diag.js:

```js
export class Diag  {
  constructor(){
      this.test = `success`;
  }
}
```

testservice.js:

```js
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {Diag} from './diag';

@inject(Diag)
export class TestService{ 
  constructor(diag){
    console.log(diag);
  }
}

>undefined.
```

In the console I only get 'undefined'. However, if I do it without DI it works fine:

```js
import {Diag} from './diag';

export class TestService{ 
  constructor(){
    console.log(Diag);
  }
}
```

So if I import it with no DI it works, but once I try to do DI like I see in the online examples it tells me that the class is undefined. I'm very confused. Any help?

Comment: For me it works properly, but I'm using TypeScript with `@autoinject` . Maybe it's something with the transpiler? Also, are you using the latest aurelia version (beta)?

Comment: That's a good point Mike. I'm using Beta 1. Yesterday they just announced beta 2 and I should download that. I'm just worried that something in Beta 2 might break my Beta 1 code and then I'll have more issues to debug. I guess I'm paranoid from all my years as a MS developer.  LOL

Comment: Correction - yesterday was just a patch release, not Beta 2.

Comment: I did a jspm update and that cleared things up. All is good now.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you are using dependency injection to get an instance of `TestService`.

```js
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {TestService} from './test-service';

@inject(TestService)
export class App { 
  constructor(service) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jeremy - thanks for all the writing you've done on Aurelia. I've been using your blogs to learn a lot.  :-)  Re this DI issue, I am using DI with my TestService in the viewmodel js file. The odd thing is that I guess that since Aurelia is still in beta that different blog posts show different code, not to mention sometimes there is TS example code too. For example, on a post by Eisenberg he said that you have to declare your constructor as   Constructor(diag: Diag) {  ...   and this throws errors too. Lots to learn I guess.

Comment: I did a jspm update and that cleared things up.  Also, the Eisenberg suggestion I mentioned is working now too.  :-)